# Why WSL can't bind localhost:80 while using SSH local forwarding

Tags: networking, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, portforwarding

I try to using the following command to access remote server's 80 port:

```sh
ssh -L 80:remote_server:80 user@proxy_server -N
```

Everything goes OK if I use the command in my Windows `PowerShell`. I can access `localhost:80`  website using my local browser.

However, when I typed this command in `WSL2`(specifically, Ubuntu 20 04), I got the following results:

```sh
bind [127.0.0.1]:80: Permission denied
channel_setup_fwd_listener_tcpip: cannot listen to port: 80
Could not request local forwarding.
```

If I choose another uncommon port(like 8000), it'll work normally.

I'm very curious about why and hope to have an in-depth understanding of `WSL`'s network principle

Comment: Only root user can bind to ports below 1024.